# how to fix ValueError: a <= 0 in python

Tags: python, numpy

this is my code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd



attr={'data1':((0.2,1),(0.2,1)), 'data2':((0.2,1),(-1,-0.2)),
      'data3':((-1,-0.2),(0.2,1)), 'data4':((-1,-0.2),(0.2,1))}
name = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4']

for k in range(4):
    X=np.random.beta(attr[name[k]][0][0], attr[name[k]][0][1],10)
    Y=np.random.beta(attr[name[k]][1][0], attr[name[k]][1][1],10)
    name[k] = pd.DataFrame({'x':X,'y':Y})
```

I get this Error

> File "mtrand.pyx", line 1709, in mtrand.RandomState.beta ValueError: a <= 0

I need Help please

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the negative numbers in your `atrr` dictionary because the [`beta`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.beta.html)  function expects non-negative argumnents .

> numpy.random.beta(a, b, size=None)
>
> a : float or array_like of floats Alpha, **non-negative**.
>
> b : float or array_like of floats Beta, **non-negative**.